# getting last column last cell value

Tags: java, swing, jtable

> i create JTable in that table value are retrieve from data base
>   (Except fifth column) in fifth column .i enter value through keyboard
>   in fifth column but when getting value again from jtable at that time
>   i am not getting last entered value in fifth column please suggest
>   something 
>   my method code bellow

```
public class TableDataDelete implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ee) {

             int b = table.getRowCount();
            System.out.println("row count" + b);

            for (int i = 0; i <b; i++) {

                try
                {

                String str = (String) table.getModel().getValueAt(i, 3);
                String str1 = (String) table.getModel().getValueAt(i, 5);
                if (!(str1 == null)) {
                    ((DefaultTableModel)table.getModel()).removeRow(i);
                    table.repaint();
                    System.out.println("remove row no is"+i);
}
  }
                catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
                {
                   System.out.println("array index out of bound exception"+e);
                }

            }

}
    }
```

working code when i enter value of five cells it can get only first four cell from the column cant getting last entered cell value

Comment: I think the indices are 0 based. Try `getValueAt(i, 4)`

Comment: yes definitely index is 0 based but i want to get third and fifth column values that can i tried  but they can access fourth column i need third column

Comment: Yeah so why are you using 3 and 5. Should be 2 and 4

Comment: i need that column thats why i use 3 and 5

Comment: please suggest me any kind of solution

Comment: I just did offer a solution. 0, 1, 2 <- what index is the third number?

Comment: can i show my  complete code

Comment: i tried according to u but still not getting last value what i entered in fifth column

Comment: @fanky, See [Table Stop Editing](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/12/table-stop-editing/) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this code to stop cell editing to get last value

```
if(table.getCellEditor() != null){
    table.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();
}
```

Comment: i can use what you have suggest me but due to that i can access only first entered cell value after that i can not access any value

Comment: Hi fanky,Use it at the first line before  int b = table.getRowCount();